# How to set ongoing flags in builder notification?

Tags: android

How do I add flags in my notification created using the `Notification.Builder` builder? It was straightforward to add flags to the `Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)` notification declaration but not to the one I've referenced above. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Download [ROOT]")
    //.setContentText("This is a test notification")
    .setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationAction.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
// Add as notification
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.notify(111, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

for setOngoing() to Notification.Builder try this :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setContentIntent(generatePendingIntent("Notification Type"))
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setOngoing(true/false); // this is where you have to set
```

you can use Notification.Builder too but with NotificationCompat.Builder and in Android 4.1 and later you able to set `action buttons` depend on expanded notifications.

---

And to handle how what's to happen when click on notification method :

```
private PendingIntent generatePendingIntent(String type) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Intent notificationIntent;
    if (type.equals("link")) {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    } else {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DesiredActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    }
    return pendingIntent;
}
```